# Can anyone identify this valve

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, us

I have several old sinks in a house I'm working on and I think I probably need to replace or at least rebuild a few of these valves. But I'm not sure of the make much less the model.

Can anyone ID these?

Edit: this is the US. Probably installed in the late 70s

[image: valve]

Comment: Where on the planet is this?

Comment: I think  your best bet would be to take it to a plumbing supply store.  They'll not only know the part, they'll have or will be able to get replacements.  Don't bother with your local home stores.

Comment: Any maker's marks on this cartridge?

Comment: I don't think there's supposed to be an O-ring where you are seeing it.  Possible the previous owner stuck it in there to attempt to shore-up the rubber stopper.  That's the part probably needs replaced.   (I don't know the name, but it mates up to the valve seat... 'valve seat gasket' maybe?).   Anyhow, that stuff is relatively generic, you probably just need to fix up the rubber & the packing nuts.   Maybe the valve seat has gotten rough - That can often be removed with an allen wrench and replaced.  Agree with Jack, go to a "real" hardware store and they'll have all the pieces on hand

Comment: BTW - Don't be a d**k and just use the locals for identification then buy your parts online.  You want that store to still be there in the future, pay them their $3 for each gasket.  You're paying for the knowledge, the rubber is almost free.

Comment: I agree with Jack and Kyle I have been buying rebuild parts for over 40 years to repair valves like this my kit is a stainless metal box that tells you how old it is I just replace the packings and washers, that kit has saved me probably thousands, the washer on the end and possibly some valve stem packing is all it probably needs possibly a new oring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles on this, I went to two plumbing parts houses in town, the first one with the fancy showroom had no idea what it was and spent a couple minutes flipping through a catalog before giving up, the second old warehouse one the guy took a quick look and said "it's a chicago faucets quaturn" but they don't carry that line. So he printed out the part sheet for me and I found them on Amazon for $28 a pair. Thanks for all your comments and help!

The gasket kits to rebuild this cartridge cost more than the new cartridge, but I'm going to get a kit or two anyway since I've been burned with "new" cartridges that are all plastic when the old ones were all brass.